# How to render react components on server and client completely?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux, isomorphic-javascript

I need to make ES6+ isomorphic javascript app, which can render full page with data on server at first request (or w/o js on client) and navigate with client-side rendering.

There is two modules, which could make asynchronus rendering - [react-async](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async) and [react-nexus](https://github.com/elierotenberg/react-nexus). React Async can make XHR request from React components, but requires node-fibers plugin, React Nexus can make server-side Flux store, and i can't understand [how to use it](https://blog.rotenberg.io/isomorphic-apps-done-right-with-react-nexus/) for simple isomorphic data fetch request from API in React component.

Comment: What? Checkout react-starter-kit.

Comment: Can react-starter-kit get list of data from db, render it on server and send html to client? I think no.

Comment: You would have to implement that yourself of course. But react-starter-kit will help you get your isomorphic application up and running quickly.

Comment: @limelights, the problem is in react, not with kits. Is there method to implement async rendering without forking react and using fibers?